# Get select option menu in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select option in a form like this

```
<select id="name" name="name" onblur="date()">
    <option value="RAN">RAN</option>
    <option value="REE">REE</option>
    <option value="SAM">SAM</option>
    <option value="SEJAl">SEJAl</option>
</select>
```

I want to get the value of the selected item in the list when the user looses focus.
I tried the following script;

```
function date(){
    var e = document.getElementById("name");    
    var name = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; 
    console.log(name);
    //do something else....  
}
```

the console is empty. A simple document.getElementById also doesnt give me the value.
so by which method can I get the value?

thanks!

**ANSWER FOUND:**

```
$name = $('select[name=name]').val();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use e.value, like this:

```
function date(){
    var e = document.getElementById("name");    
    console.log(e.value); 
}
```

Comment: the log is still blank.. could this be because I am trying to fetch the value of an input on which an event handler is called?

Comment: I think you have an error outside of the code you've posted here. I've just tested my code and it works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DzbLn

Answer (score 1):

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/obiNAQ/1/edit)

```
function date(){
    var e = document.getElementById("name");    
    alert(e.value); 
}
```

This will shows value in `alert` perfectly, when tou select any value ant clicks outside :)